# Is possible to embed fontawesome font in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf, font-awesome

I'd like to use fontawesome in pdf. I generate my pdf using php library fpdf and font embedding. However I cannot make it works.

I use this tool to generate afm file: http://fpdf.fruit-lab.de/

But when I try to use fontawesome I always get white square instead of icons.

I use this syntax to add icon:

```
MultiCell(0,8,"\uF000 ",0,'C')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot answer for fpdf since I have never used it.  However, I do use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) and there I use fontawesome regularly - no issues at all.  The only thing I have to ensure is that the content I output to the PDF document (mPDF takes this in the form of HTML markup) hast to be UTF8 encoded.

mPDF is very good so if you are at an early stage of your project you might just consider switching to it.  Otherwise, it is worth exploring whether you too are not running into a UTF8 encoding issue.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I cannot switch to mPdf at this point of my project. Mpdf seems based on fpdf, this let me think that probably it's possible also in fpdf. If I can ask, mpdf font embedding works like fpdf? you should create an afm file from fontawesome? which tool do you use to create afm?

Comment: Since mpdf 5, around 3 years ago, it is no longer necessary to convert font files to a special format.  I simply use the TTF variant of fontawesome.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @DroidOS can you please explain how to use fontawesome in mpdf? Thanks in advance

Comment: @arilia - take a look at [https://www.kanuhawaii.org/actions/mpdf/examples/example53_new_mPDF_v5-0_fonts.php](https://www.kanuhawaii.org/actions/mpdf/examples/example53_new_mPDF_v5-0_fonts.php).  It has all the information you need.  It really, couldn't be any easier!

Comment: hello @DroidOS, I am having trouble with FA icons not showing up in my PDF. here's the whole information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453168/fontawesome-icons-wont-show-on-generated-pdf-using-mpdf?noredirect=1#comment48988633_30453168 I hope you could be able to help me.

Comment: @kaynewilder - I wish I could help.  It has been a long time since I did anything with mPDF.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out even though this thread is over a year old. It *is* possible to use font-awesome although you can only use up to 256 characters per subset. I created several character maps to encompass all of the glyphs as of font awesome version 4.3.0. You just use the map that contains the characters you're going to use or you can make three subsets of it. It's not necessarily as performant as other solutions, but **fPDF** is still much faster than some of the alternatives because it is lacking a lot of the more modern features like unicode support.

- http://code.deweyartdesign.com/fpdf/makefont/fa1.map
- http://code.deweyartdesign.com/fpdf/makefont/fa2.map
- http://code.deweyartdesign.com/fpdf/makefont/fa3.map

First, you need to use **ttf2pt1** to create the afm file for the font.

```
    ttf2pt1 -a fontawesome-webfont.ttf fontawesome-webfont
```

I made three copies of the webfont to run through makefont.php and used each encoding on the corresponding font.

```
    require "makefont.php";

    makefont('fontawesome-webfont1.ttf','fa1.map');
    makefont('fontawesome-webfont2.ttf','fa2.map');
    makefont('fontawesome-webfont3.ttf','fa3.map');
```

To use them in fPDF, put the files generated in the font folder and add them like this:

```
    $pdf->AddFont('FA1','',fontawesome-webfont1.php);
    $pdf->AddFont('FA2','',fontawesome-webfont2.php);
    $pdf->AddFont('FA3','',fontawesome-webfont3.php);
```

Then you use the character number to render the glyph for the corresponding subset of font-awesome. The three font maps above contain the character numbers to use :

```
    $pdf->SetFont('FA1','',14);

    $WineGlass = chr(32);

    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$WineGlass);
```

I also made a character map generator that will show the character numbers below the glyphs.

```
    <?php

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/fpdf.php');

    // Establish / Get variables

    function GETVAR($key, $default = null, $prefix = null, $suffix = null) {
        return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $prefix . $_GET[$key] . $suffix : $prefix . $default . $suffix;
    }

    $font = GETVAR('font','fontawesome-webfont1','','.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF('L','mm',array(268.33,415.3));

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(0,0);
    // add custom fonts

    $pdf->AddFont('H','','helvetica.php');

    $pdf->AddFont('FA','',$font);

    $pdf->SetFillColor(200,200,200);

    $pdf->SetXY(9,9);

    for ($i = 32; $i <= 256; $i++) {

        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $x = $pdf->GetX();

        $pdf->SetX($x);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $pdf->SetFont('FA','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(12,12,chr($i),1,0,'C');

        $pdf->SetXY($x,$y+12);

        $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $pdf->SetFont('H','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(12,12,$i,1,0,'C',1);

        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $x = $pdf->GetX();

        $pdf->SetXY($x,$y-12);

        if ($x > 400) {
         $pdf->SetXY(9,$y+14);       
        }

        if ($i == 328){
            $pdf->AddPage();
        }

    }

    $pdf->Output("charmap.pdf",'I');
```

Comment: tried this with font awesome 4.5 and i'm just getting squares.  could you explain how you made the map files so i can try to make new ones for the latest font awesome?

Comment: The map files are now documented on my [wiki](https://deweyartdesign.com/wiki/code/fpdf)

Comment: They were created manually by examining current map files and comparing the maps to the corresponding font php files/maps. I did plenty of experimentation until I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the font-awesome and re-map it to A-Z characters,
and that way, use it easily in fpdf.

```
// Import and prepare font for usage by engine:
$pdf->AddFont('fontawesome-123-full','','fontawesome-123-full.php');
...
// print FontAwesome's asterisk
$pdf->Text($x, $y, chr(0x21));
```

You can download the ready font and ready-to-use FPDF font files here:

http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2021/12/using-fontawesome-in-php-fpdf.html