# Use FontAwesome in tFPDF

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I am using [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)

> This class is a modified version of FPDF that adds UTF-8 support.
>   Moreover, it embeds only the necessary parts of the fonts that are
>   used in the document, making the file size much smaller than if the
>   whole fonts were embedded. These features were originally developed
>   for the mPDF project.

Is it possible to include FontAwesome for that class?

**First Try:**
I downloaded [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/). I uploaded at http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ the file `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` which then produced `fontawesome-webfont.php`, however with a lots of warnings:

[image]

I moved `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` to `tfpdf/font/unifont` and `fontawesome-webfont.php` to `tfpdf/font/`. I used the [Font Dump script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script4.php) to check if the font was correctly loaded but

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddFont('FontAwesome','','fontawesome-webfont.ttf',true);
$pdf->DumpFont('FontAwesome');
$pdf->Output();
```

only generated

[image]

**Second Try:**
I found at [Is possible to embed fontawesome font in fpdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369388/is-possible-to-embed-fontawesome-font-in-fpdf/31485855#31485855) a similar question for fPDF. 
I tried to follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485855/2311074 but `ttf2pt1` seems to be [outdated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927687/how-to-install-ttf2pt1). I tried to follow the instruction with `ttf2ps1` but it did not produce the required output. Also I am not sure what he means with `run through makefont.php`. This file seems to not exist anymore.

**Question** Can I include fontawesome in tFPDF or something similar? I am aware of the `SYMBOL` font thats integrated in tFPDF. However, I need 3 symbols, a telephone, an email and world. There is no world icon in the `SYMBOL` font and the email icon loos really bad. WOuld be happy about any support.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you're asking for, but you're using a modified FPDF class and adding a font just to get three symbols? Why not just use images for those?

Comment: Yes I could do this also. But then I have to worry about the margins between the symbol and the text. Also adding a new font was so far pretty easy.