# INR Currency Symbol Add in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to add INR Currency Symbol in pdf file using fpdf. how to add INR Currency Symbol (Rupee) pdf file using fpdf.

Comment: You would probably need to include a font that includes the character ₹.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: See [fpdf's makefont tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible to embed fontawesome font in fpdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369388/is-possible-to-embed-fontawesome-font-in-fpdf)

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/inr/

Answer (score 0):

See fpdf font dump documentation

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script4.php .

Here, No option to add rupee symbol (₹) so, u can use rupee symbol png image and integrate with fpdf.

$pdf->Image('rupee.png',8,10,-200);

Comment: "See docu" is usually not considered a helpful answer. Also just linking to what you provide as solution is not considered a lastingly helpful answer, because external links might rot. Please summarise the core of the helpful part of the documentation directly here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to print the rupee sign with FPDF:

- Copy the cp1252.map file (located in the makefont directory) to cp1252+INR.map.
- Open cp1252+INR.map in a text editor. Replace this line:

`!A4 U+00A4 currency`

with:

`!A4 U+20B9 uni20B9`

This will map the rupee sign at position 0xA4 (instead of the generic [currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography))).

- Choose a font that contains the rupee sign and use `MakeFont()` with the `cp1252+INR` encoding to convert it. Here I will use the Arial font that comes with Windows:

```
<?php
require('makefont/makefont.php');

MakeFont('C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf', 'cp1252+INR');
?>
```

Copy the generated files (arial.php and arial.z) to the font directory.

- Add the font in your script and use `chr(0xA4)`:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Arial', '', 'arial.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 20);
$pdf->Write(5, 'Rupee sign: '.chr(0xA4));
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is pretty late but a simple solution to this issue would be to use tFPDF which is essentially an extension to FPDF. Using tFPDF, you can use the 'DejaVu Sans' font which supports the '₹' symbol along with most other currency symbols. This font comes in packed with the tFPDF as well, so you can literally plug it in and use it in your current system directly.
More information can be found here:

http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=92

```
<?php

// Optionally define the filesystem path to your system fonts
// otherwise tFPDF will use [path to tFPDF]/font/unifont/ directory
// define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "C:/Windows/Fonts/");

require('tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

// Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Write(5,'The file size of this PDF is only 13 KB.');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Cheers!!